# Running Authorization Server behind API Gateway

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-authorization-server, spring-boot-oauth2.1

I am upgrading my existing authorization server to the newest version according to
https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started.html

As the next step, I am trying to run the Authorization Server behind an API Gateway.

Without API Gateway, everything is working as expected, but when the service is accessible through API Gateway the flow is not working.
This is due to lots of forwarding happening internally in the library.
My questions are:

1. Is it a valid assumption that Authorization Server is accessible only from API Gateway?
2. Why it is so difficult to configure authorization server behind a reverse proxy, like API Gateway?
3. What is the best way to configure Authorization Server behind an API Gateway?

Configured login url from a relative path to an absolute one, still have problem with configuring cookie. Consent form path config yet to come.